# Unable To view source code of my angular web-app in developer console when my project is running live but can be seen when running locally

Tags: angular, frontend, server-side-rendering, source-maps

I was recently working on the **creation of the content** for my **angular developer roadmap series** but while working on of the content i encountered with the situation which had been stucked into my mind since a week.
Basically, the issue which i faced was that for my angular web app i am **unable see the source code in developer console of my angular application when my project is running live but when i ran the same project locally i can see the same source code of my angular application.**

I had tried the solution of **"source-map" **but this solution did'nt work for me.
Any other help or the usage of source-map will also workout for me.
i had deep dived into SSR from my end.Requesting all to please help me out onto this.

My Desired Output is that i should be able to see the source code of my angular web app when running it onto live server too.

Comment: are you using `build` or `serve` command? do you have `--configuration` flag set up correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your response . Answering your first question i am using build command and my --configuration flag is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you build angular application your build output resides in dist directory which has all the static assets along with your all javascript source code file compiled and minified. This contents is used for live production deployment thus you will not be able to see the source code structure in production/live mode. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: Thank you for your response but the challenge here i want to show the html source whenever they want to help them to make it easy to debug